# Manipulate number of squares in a grid matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Right now I have a grid in my plots using the option

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.grid(True)
```

Because of the nature of my plot, the lines of the grid are at every 500 units in x and every 5 units in y. Is there a way where I can increment the number of horizontal lines (i.e. increment to a line per y unit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `which='minor'`, but you need to turn on minor ticks first. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
ax = plt.gca()
minor_ticks = np.arange(0,100,5)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(which='minor')
plt.show()
```

[image]